# Selecting the attribute value of the last of an element

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm trying to display the number of pages in a document by taking the `@n` value of the last `<pb/>` in the document. Right now, I'm still getting the value of the first `<pb/>`. Here's my input xml:

```
<p><line>While a prisoner here remains in their</line> 
            <line>so-called 1st grade, he is able to write</line> 
            <line>twice a week, in second grade once a week,</line> 
            <line>and in third grade once a month. These</line> 
            <line>grades refer to classifications that ostensibly</line>
            <line>are for conduct while here.  It is quite possible</line> 
            <line>to lose a conduct rating, as I understand it,</line> 
            <line>by not having a perpetually rusting tin cup polished</line> 
            <pb n="2"/>
            <line>brightly for daily inspection, although the tin plating long ago dis-</line>
            <line>appeared and the cup is rusty again within 2 hours after wetting.</line></p>
        <p><line>The food here is good and is well-cooked,</line> 
            <line>with one exception, the gravy, which is nothing but</line> 
            <line>flour, water, and bacon grease, Strangely enough, how-</line>
            <line>ever, no condiments, not even salt, are provided on</line> 
            <pb n="3"/>
            <line>the table, to the detriment of otherwise very good</line> 
            <line>meals.  While meat here is unrationed and is plentiful,</line> 
            <line>toilet paper; believe it or not, is rationed.  A</line> 
            <line>5¢ roll must last a prisoner 45 days, or else -- ?</line>
            <line>Perhaps, however, a prisoner can purchase additional</line> 
            <line>if it should be necessary.</line></p>
```

And here's my xsl:

```
<dt>Pages:</dt>
            <dd>
                <xsl:if test="//pb">
                    <xsl:value-of select="//pb[position()=last()]/@n"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </dd>
```

How can I select the `@n` value of the last `<pb/>` in the entire document?

Comment: Actually I think this is correct. You could try `(//pb/@n)[last()]` instead but I don't see why your xpath should not work. Maybe you can provide some of your html code?

Comment: Added the xml, which is what I was transforming.

Comment: @Misenus The XML you show is not well-formed, thus useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always found the position function a bit tricky to use, but it's probably only a personal feeling. Nevermind, the tricky part is the fact that the context used by the position() function is not necessarly the context you're using to grab the nodes. In your code, for example, you select all the  elements disregarding of where they are. But if they are "alone" in their parent, they could match the predicate position()=last() cause they are "last" in their parent.

Usually, I'd use some xpath like this (maybe not optimal in time process for very large documents) :

```
<xsl:value-of select="//pb[not(following::pb)]/@n"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The  problem with your approach:

```
<xsl:value-of select="//pb[position()=last()]/@n"/>
```

is that `//pb[position()=last()]` selects all `pb` elements that are the last `pb` children of their parents<sup>1</sup>. You then take the value of the first one of these.

In order to select the last `pb` element in the entire document you should do either:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/descendant::pb[last()]/@n" />
```

or:

```
<xsl:value-of select="(//pb)[last()]/@n" />
```

Of course, this will only work with a well-formed XML input. The example you have provided is not.

--
1. http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev